# Is there a consensus that there are racial differences in IQ scores?

Tags: iq

I'm not asking whether the difference is genetic or environmental, or if IQ scores are a racist and flawed measure of intelligence. i.e., I am not asking about causation.

Is there a consensus that today, in e.g. America, there are differences in IQ scores?

I think it is far less racist to assume that black American IQ scores are, at an individual level, on average a standard deviation less than what they measure

Comment: Given the correlations between IQ and socioeconomic status and education, and the racial disparities in the US in those measures, what do you think is the value in asking this question?

Comment: that's a fair point, thanks @BryanKrause

Comment: it'd undermine 'iq' as well as the idea we're post race, etc.. i don't see the problem

Comment: I don't know if it would "undermine" IQ beyond what is already known: IQ is a bad measure for comparing across groups of people. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_models_are_wrong As far as being "post race" I don't know that serious scholars make any claim for that as more than a theoretical idea, but that doesn't have much to do with IQ and has a lot more to do with those socioeconomic discrepancies.

Comment: I'd say that generally we can agree on that much; controversy comes further on. Actually it's even true by definition; as IQ tests aren't ethnicity-normalized there will always be average differences (albeit perhaps insignificantly small). However, this alone doesn't mean much without further assumptions. As you noted, IQ tests could still have different meanings across populations, and aren't inherent (e.g. are environmentally contaminated), so such simple comparisons are largely meaningless.

Comment: just to clarify: I do not think this question is racist. I think it is less racist to assume that black American iq scores are, at an individual level, a standard deviation less than what they measure. cheers

Comment: I don't understand what this last comment means.  The duplicate question links to 2 other duplicate questions; between them this question has been asked to death on this forum.  Answers discuss whether there is a gap, what is the gap, how to interpret the gap, and what might cause the gap, all at length.  I really don't see what this question adds that hasn't been covered previously.

Comment: sorry @ArnonWeinberg I have no idea what you don't understand. or why you think these questions ask the exact same thing. perhaps you are confused into thinking IQ = G , rather than a measurement of it?